# warning in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

warning: (Messages without a matching method signature

warning: no '-eventListArray' method found

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[[popularListArray objectAtIndex:section]eventListArray]count];

}
```

@Thanks in advance

Comment: ]eventListArray]count] it seems that you confused with "[]"

Comment: Did you import the header file that declares eventListArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you need to `#import` the header file in which the `-eventListArray` method is declared.

Files are compiled one at a time, so if you don't import the header, the compiler won't know about the method when compiling this file and will therefore issue a warning.

Comment: you are correct dave delong....... I forget to import the Headerfile.... its listing warning......no '-eventListArray' method found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to silence compiler you have to cast the object you retrieve by popularListArray because objectAtIndex return an (id) which is a (*void) equivalent.